# Argue that the maximal interval of existence for the solution $y$ is $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be open, $\left(t_{0}, x_{0}\right) \in U$, and $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function which is also uniformly Lipschitz continuous in the second variable. Consider the initial value problem (IVP)

$$
x^{\prime}(t)=f(t, x(t)) \text { with } x\left(t_{0}\right)=x_{0} .
$$

In a previous question I have proven that

*(a) Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $J \subset \mathbb{R}$ be intervals such that $\left(t_{0}, x_{0}\right) \in I \times J \subset U$. Assume $x_{1}: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $x_{2}: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are solutions of the IVP in $(1), x_{1}(I) \subset J$, and $x_{2}(I) \subset J$. Then $x_{1}=x_{2}$.*

I have proven that there exists a unique solution on a nonempty set $I$ using the Picard-Lindelof theorem. Also given is

*If $x$ is a solution to the IVP (1), its maximal interval of existence is the largest interval on which a solution to the IVP exists that coincides with $x$ on the domain of $x$. *

*It can be shown that if a unique solution $x$ of (1) exists on some nonempty interval, then it has a maximal interval of existence of the form $\left(T_{-}, T_{+}\right)$, for some $T_{-} \in \mathbb{R} \cup\{-\infty\}$ and some $T_{+} \in \mathbb{R} \cup\{+\infty\}$. (Note that $T_{\pm}$may depend on $\left(t_{0}, x_{0}\right)$.*

*Moreover, if $T_{+}<+\infty$, then for every closed and bounded set $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $\left[t_{0}, T_{+}\right] \times K \subset$ $U$ and for every $\delta>0$, there exists a $t \in\left(T_{+}-\delta, T_{+}\right)$such that $x(t) \notin K$. Similarly, if $T_{-}>-\infty$, then for every closed and bounded set $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $\left[T_{-}, t_{0}\right] \times K \subset U$ and for every $\delta>0$, there exists a $t \in\left(T_{-}, T_{-}+\delta\right)$ such that $x(t) \notin K$.*

**The question:**

(e) Argue that the maximal interval of existence for the solution $y$ (derived in an earlier question as noted above) is $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. that $y(t)$ exists for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

**My attempt:** *edited after a correction by Lutz Lehmann*

I could argue that the limit $L$ of $y(t)$ exists for $t\rightarrow T_+$. Because the maximum interval of existance has to be open and it has to include the new point $T_+$, the interval will be bigger. I can choose a $\delta>0$ such that there exists a $t_1\in{T_+-\delta,T_+}$ with $x(t_1)\notin{K}$. But how would I choose the interval $K$? and how can I use it to argue that for all $t_1\in{T_+-\delta,T_+}$, $|x(t)-L|<\varepsilon$ for a chosen $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: This makes no sense. If $K=y(I)$ and $t_1\in I$, then automatically $y(t_1\in K$. You can modify the proof construction of Picard-Lindelöf so that it applies uniformly, with the same constants, for any initial point $(t_1,y(t_1))$ with $t_1\in I$. Or you could argue that the limit of $y(t)$ for $t\to T_+$ must exist, and that the local solution around it is a continuation.

Comment: Oke i see now. As you said i could argue that the limit $L$ of $y(t)$ exists for $t\rightarrow T_+$. Because the maximum interval of existance has to be open and it has to include the new point $T_+$, the interval will be bigger. I can choose a $\delta>0$ such that there exists a $t_1\in{T_+-\delta,T_+}$ with $x(t_1)\notin{K}$. But how would I choose the interval $K$? and how can I use it to argue that for all $t_1\in{T_+-\delta,T_+}$, $|x(t)-L|<\varepsilon$ for a chosen $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: If you want to argue via "leaves every compact set inside the domain", then construct a suitable one. Pick $I=[t_1, T_++δ]$, $a=|I|$, $y_1=y(t_1)$, estimate the maximum of $f$ as $M=\max|f(I,y_1)|+La$, set $b=Ma$. Then the solution can not leave $K=I\times[y_1-b,y_1+b]$ in forward time direction at the top or bottom, which is a contradiction, as the right side is also not reached.